# Pick 3 random elements from an array. And not get the same elements twice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this function to print out three random names without using the same name twice. I started trying with an If inside the for-loop, but have no idea if that is correct. Appriciate all help as i feel kinda stuck at this point in learning Javascript.

```
var name = ["Kai", "Lars", "Anders", "Ole", "Petter", "Mikael", "Cos", "Sin"];  
var randName = [];

    function randomNavn(){
        document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = "";
        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            randName.push(name.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length), 1));

            if(name[i] === randName[i]){

            }
        }
        document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = randName.join(" , ");
    }
```

Comment: Is the question "is this correct" ? Try it and see, if it doesn't work, post a question with your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `do..while` loop. Note also `[0]` at close of `.splice()` to return value of array instead of array.

```js
var names = ["Kai", "Lars", "Anders", "Ole"
             , "Petter", "Mikael", "Cos", "Sin"];  
var randName = [];
do {
  randName[randName.length] = names.splice(
                                Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)
                              , 1)[0];
} while (randName.length < 3);

console.log(randName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a different variable name than `name`, because it is a protected property of the window object.

```js
function randomNavn(){
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        randName.push(nname.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * nname.length), 1));
    }
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = randName.join(", ");
}

var nname = ["Kai", "Lars", "Anders", "Ole", "Petter", "Mikael", "Cos", "Sin"],
    randName = [];

randomNavn();
```

```html
<div id="utskrift"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For you, that will be

```
var name = ["Kai", "Lars", "Anders", "Ole", "Petter", "Mikael", "Cos", "Sin"];  
var randName = [];
function randomNavn(){
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = "";
    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        randName.push(name.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length), 1));
        if(name[i] === randName[i]){
            i-- // yay, that's all!
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = randName.join(" , ");
}
```

Another vay:

```
var i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
var i2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (name.length-1));
if (i2 >= i1) i2++;
var i2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (name.length-2));
if (i3 >= i2) i3++;
if (i3 >= i1) i3++;
```